# can the sharepoint 2010 PeopleEditor control be used to lookup Active Directory users/groups?

Tags: sharepoint-2010

i know that 2007 you can NOT search Active Directory, only users/groups that exists in the site collection.  Have they changed the implementation of this for 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is yes. I am by no means an AD expert, but when I go to choose a user you can either type out part or all of their display or user name, active directory will then go through and find the closest match.   Then there is the actual search which allows you to type in "matt" for example and get a list of all the matt's in sharepoint or active directory.  It doesn't however let you do a blank search to enumerate everything as the people picker in windows will let you do.  You have to enter a string to search by.

I'll also refer to this post because I'm betting they work in the same way.
http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/10/09/how-does-person-or-group-column-really-work.aspx